# Custom Form Expression Constraints working in QGIS, but not in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I am trying to create a custom form that can be used for door to door surveys. Depending on how one question is answered, there might need to be some follow-up questions or null values in the survey.

I created the following expression based constraint:

`if("Response or" is  'Response' ,  "Residence?" is not NULL,  "Residence?" is NULL)`

I apply this same constraint to 5 different fields and it works perfectly on all 5 fields in QGIS. I am able to sync the project with QField and see the form exactly how I set it up in QGIS.  The expression constraint works in the first 3 of the 5 fields, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the last 2 fields to work in QField. The fields that are not working use a very simple value map: `NULL`, `Yes`, or `No`, which is the same value map as one of the fields that is working.

The non-working fields are there, and when I select yes to response, all 5 fields turn red. But when I choose an yes/no answer for those fields, they do not turn green like the other fields. I have tested on both an Android and app3le device and experience the same problem.

Here are some screen shots from QGIS, showing how it works, and QField showing how it doesn't:
[image: Once I choose Response, the fields show that they cannot be null in QGIS]
[image: All 5 conditional Fields working in QGIS]

[image: In the QField App, all 5 fields turn red to show that they cannot be Null]

[image: Even though they are using the same formula as the other fields, the last two fields do not turn green after being answered.]

Comment: It may be me, but I'm finding your post hard to follow. Simplify. You need to explicitly state field names, value map's, give constraint expresions for each, and show screenshots of where these are applied. Perhaps start with one field that isn't working.

Comment: I figured it out. Some of the field properties were slightly different. The fields worked as expected in QGIS, but did not work in as expected in QField. I had to delete the feilds and play with it until I found something that work.